# TypeError: argument must be sequence while using Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

The goal is to overlay `pfp` on top of template, and then place the string `description` underneath `pfp`. When I run the code, I get the error `TypeError: argument must be sequence`.

```
def edit(template, pfp, description):
    x = (template.size[0] - image.size[0])/2
    y = (template.size[1] - image.size[1])/2
    Image.Image.paste(template, pfp, (round(x), round(y)))

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(template)
    draw.text(round((template.size[0]/8), round(y-15)), description)

    template.show()
    return template
```

Full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shalim/PycharmProjects/EDPtigerstars/main.py", line 30, in <module>
    edit(background, image, x[1]).save(x[0])
  File "/Users/shalim/PycharmProjects/EDPtigerstars/main.py", line 18, in edit
    draw.text(round((template.size[0]/8), round(y-15)), description)
  File "/Users/shalim/PycharmProjects/EDPtigerstars/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 512, in text
    draw_text(ink)
  File "/Users/shalim/PycharmProjects/EDPtigerstars/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 496, in draw_text
    self.draw.draw_bitmap(coord, mask, ink)
TypeError: argument must be sequence

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `x, y` coordinates inside a tuple:

```
draw.text((x,y)), "Text")
```